# Liferay 5.2.3 CE Migration from Windows Server 2008 R2 to Ubuntu Server 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, liferay

I want to migrate Liferay 5.2.3 CE from Windows Server 2008 R2 to Ubuntu Server 12.10.

The required changes for migration are done as follow:

1)Copied document_library and imported the Mysql dump.

2)The portal-ext.properties file entries are configured correctly for Mysql database

3)Deleted sevencogs folders

4)Java is configured for Oracle JDK

After all configuration it is not able to migrate sucessfully to Linux machine. But new installation of Liferay is working fine.

Similar to above issue question is asked here: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/11823660 but not answered completely.

Comment: What do you mean "not able to migrate sucessfully" ?
Does it start ? Does it migrate a part of the old informations ? Does it spit stack traces ?
Did you migrate your `context.xml` along with your portal ?

Comment: It is started with default liferay data and not taking my old data of the portal.

Comment: Did you migrate your context.xml along with your portal ?
Can you be more specific on what is (or isn't) installed ?
What files did you override in your liferay server's files ? In your tomcat's files ?

Comment: I have not copied context.xml . Only document_libraray folder is copied and database dump is imported from old portal. Let me know what other information is required?

Comment: what is the result of ls in your $LIFERAY_SERVER directory ?
in $LIFERAY_SERVER/conf ?

Comment: Thanks for your support. Finally I am able to solve this issue. It was because of different case-sensitive nature for table names on windows and Linux. Reference Link http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/10299609

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When migrating the Liferay from Windows to Linux one important checkpoint is the table names cases. As different naming convention is followed by windows and Linux. To follow the same lower-case naming convention on Linux we can edit **lower_case_table_names = 1** under  **'/etc/mysql/my.cnf'** .

Reference Links:

http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/14068722

AND

http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/10299609